# I want to screenshot youtube videos for an app. I can do this with clip to onenote chrome extension but don't know how to emulate the functionality

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, clip, onenote

So clip to OneNote and other clipping extensions can screenshot everything on the page including content in an iframe. Does anyone know how they do that? I figure it's some sort of javascript functionality. When I tried to use html2canvas, they said it wouldn't be possible to grab the iframe. As far as security issues go, this screenshot would be rendered clientside.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the captureVisibleTab api with the "`<all_urls>`" permission.

"Captures the visible area of the currently active tab in the specified window."

```
chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(
 chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT,
 { format: "png" || "jpeg" },
 function(dataurl) {
  console.log(dataurl)
 }
)
```

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-captureVisibleTab

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted. I presume you can't use the api without making a chrome extension? Just wanted to check.

Comment: Yes, you need a Chrome or Firefox extension to use the api.

Answer (score 0):

Answered above

developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-captureVisibleTa‌​b